# Play Framework taking too long to run

Tags: java, playframework, command-prompt

Before my laptop was reformatted, I can easily develop with Play. After my laptop was reformatted and I installed play, when I try to run a Play-Java project, it takes forever to load. I haven't gathered enough patience so I always cancel it (Ctrl + D). I tried waiting about 30 mins or so but to no progression at all. Yes, I also tried to run a new simple project but it acts the same.

**When I execute the run command, I immediately go to my browser and render the page (localhost:9000). Then it only took a couple of seconds after that. It seems like I am forcing my browser to render the page.**

[What I mean by 'forcing'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QULkH.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43NCl.png)

So what I'm wondering is why does the usual process take forever in my laptop until the time that I 'force' it?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Ryan Stull Why do I need to force it rather than going the correct process of waiting for run to finish executing before I enter localhost:9000 to my browser?

Comment: @Ryan see update :)

Comment: Your image doesn't make it all that clear what "forcing" means, and the question might benefit from a textual description. In any case, are you able to add some profiling code to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @halfer after I enter "run" in cmd, I go directly to the browser and type "localhost:9000" (rendering the page). The usual process is wait for the "run" command to successfully execute before you type in "localhost:9000" . If I do this usual process, it'll take forever for the run command to finish executing.My process is, I need to enter the run command and go render the page(type in localhost:9000 on my browser) without waiting for the run command to successfully execute. That process works for me it's not really a problem anymore, I can develop now with play as I said in my answer below.

Comment: @halfer I did not put any code yet, it's the standard application that comes when you create a new play-java app through command prompt. It should display the "page" I posted above as image with description "The result".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I discovered that I can force it, it's not really that of a problem. If I can develop with Play Framework now, then I'm good. Even though it's an odd way of running it. So when you encounter this difficulty too, try my method maybe it will work for you :)